# Get simple Admin Sdk Example (e.g. add custom CMS element or menuitem) to life

Tags: cloud, shopware6

Tried to do it like in docu, but didnt work yet.

No Error Messages - just nothing happens.

I think we are currently missing some important connections for understanding.

(would prefer german answer, if possible)

---

FEATURE_NEXT_17950=1

add to manifest.xml

```
<admin>
        <base-app-url>
            https://url_to_index_file/
        </base-app-url>
</admin>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/cdn"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regenerator-runtime"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

        <script src="/module/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>

    </script>
</html>
```

(see https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/ui/menuItem)
main.js - menuItem:

```
if (sw.location.isIframe()) {
 if (sw.location.is(sw.location.MAIN_HIDDEN)) {
        console.log('here') // is thrown successfully!
        // Add the menu item to the catalogue module
        sw.ui.menu.addMenuItem({
            label: 'Test item',
            displaySearchBar: true,
            locationId: 'your-location-id',
            parent: 'sw-catalogue'
        });
  }

    // Render your custom view
    if (sw.location.is('your-location-id')) {
        console.log('here2') // not triggered, cause no menuitem to go to inserted
        document.body.innerHTML = '<h1 style="text-align: center">Hello from your menu item</h1>';
    }
}
```

main.js - custom cms element:

```
//import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'; doesnt work

if (sw.location.isIframe()) {
    if (sw.location.is(sw.location.MAIN_HIDDEN)) {
        // Execute the base commands
        import('./base/mainCommands.js');
    } else {
        // Render different views
        console.log('else') // never get triggered
        import('./viewRenderer.js');
    }
}
```

/base/mainCommands.js:

```
const CMS_ELEMENT_NAME = 'test';
const CONSTANTS = {
    CMS_ELEMENT_NAME,
    PUBLISHING_KEY: `${CMS_ELEMENT_NAME}__config-element`,
};

function test() {
    console.log('done 0') // triggered successful
    sw.cms.registerCmsElement({
        name: CONSTANTS.CMS_ELEMENT_NAME,
        label: 'Test video',
        defaultConfig: {
            dailyUrl: {
                source: 'static',
                value: '',
            },
        },
    });
    console.log('done 1') // triggered successful
}

try {
    test();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}

console.log('done 3') // triggered successful

export default CONSTANTS;
```

viewRenderer.js:

```
// import Vue from 'vue'; doesnt work

// watch for height changes
sw.location.startAutoResizer();

// start app views
const app = new Vue({
    // el: '#app', // no access yet
    data() {
        return { sw.location };
    },
    components: {
        'TestElement':
            () => import('./views/elements/test/test-element.js'),
        'TestConfig':
            () => import('./views/elements/test/test-config.js'),
        'TestPreview':
            () => import('./views/elements/test/test-preview.js'),

    },
    template: `
        <TestElement
            v-if="sw.location.is('test-element')"
        ></TestElement>
        <TestConfig
            v-else-if="sw.location.is('test-config')"
        ></TestConfig>
        <TestPreview
            v-else-if="sw.location.is('test-preview')"
        ></TestPreview>
    `,
});
```

/views/elements/test/test-config.js

```
// import Vue from 'vue'; // doesnt work
import CONSTANTS from "../../../base/mainCommands";

export default Vue.extend({
    template: `
        <div>
          <h2>
            Config!
          </h2>
          Video-Code: <input v-model="dailyUrl" type="text"/><br/>
        </div>
    `,

    data(): Object {
        return {
            element: null
        }
    },

    computed: {
        dailyUrl: {
            get(): string {
                return this.element?.config?.dailyUrl?.value || '';
            },

            set(value: string): void {
                this.element.config.dailyUrl.value = value;

                sw.data.update({
                    id: CONSTANTS.PUBLISHING_KEY,
                    data: this.element,
                });
            }
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.createdComponent();
    },

    methods: {
        async createdComponent() {
            this.element = await data.get({ id: CONSTANTS.PUBLISHING_KEY });
        }
    }
});
```

/views/elements/test/test-element.js

```
// import Vue from 'vue'; // doesnt work
import CONSTANTS from "../../../base/mainCommands";

export default Vue.extend({
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2>
              Element!
            </h2>
            <div class="sw-cms-el-dailymotion">
                <div class="sw-cms-el-dailymotion-iframe-wrapper">
                <!--
                    <iframe
                        frameborder="0"
                        type="text/html"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        :src="dailyUrl">
                    </iframe>
                    -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,

    data(): { element: object|null } {
        return {
            element: null
        }
    },

    computed: {
        dailyUrl(): string {
            return `https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/${this.element?.config?.dailyUrl?.value || ''}`;
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.createdComponent();
    },

    methods: {
        async createdComponent() {
            this.element = await sw.data.get({ id: CONSTANTS.PUBLISHING_KEY });
            sw.data.subscribe(CONSTANTS.PUBLISHING_KEY, this.elementSubscriber);
        },

        elementSubscriber(response: { data: unknown, id: string }): void {
            this.element = response.data;
        }
    }
});
```

/views/elements/test/test-preview.js

```
// import Vue from 'vue'; // doesnt work

export default Vue.extend({
    template: `
        <h2>
          Preview!
        </h2>
    `,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The guide you're trying to follow was originally written in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and assumed that you [compile your code e.g. using Node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/compile-typescript-code-npm?view=vs-2022) before deploying it. TypeScript can't be executed natively by the browser. You'll have to rewrite it as plain JavaScript if you don't want to compile it. Additionally, if you're loading Vue from a CDN you don't have to import it. I would however recommend to setup a development environment so you may compile the code.